# Google script Execution failed: please try again later and consider using batch operations. The user is over quota

Tags: google-apps-script, google-contacts-api

I have a script where I'm syncing my google contacts with google spreadsheet.
I have around 11000 contacts in my account and I've written a function getContacts which fetches all contact information from the google contacts and sends it to a function printContacts,how ever as there are too many contacts the script fails to execute to completion.
I tried using the code to create a trigger everytime the max execution time is reached but now I'm facing a new problem,as I have too many ContactsApi call the script is showing an error saying 'user quota exceeded'
If anyone can get this code to work,it'd be a great help

```
//Function gets the contacts from the Google Contacts and stores in an array. Calls printContacts function with that array and no. of rows as argument
    function getContacts() {
      var startTime= (new Date()).getTime();
      Logger.log("start time set")

      var scriptProperties = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties();
      var num_contacts = scriptProperties.getProperty('num_contacts');
      Logger.log("script property num_contacts : "+Number(num_contacts))

      setHeader();
      var groupName = 'System Group: My Contacts';    
      var group  = ContactsApp.getContactGroup(groupName);
      var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
      var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
      var contacts = ContactsApp.getContactsByGroup(group);

      var allContacts = []; 
      var contactDetails = [];
      var data, numData, dataArray = [], extraArray = [];
      var contact_length = contacts.length;
      Logger.log("contact_length : "+contact_length);
      Logger.log("contacts.length : "+contacts.length);
      var MAX_RUNNING_TIME = 300000;
      var REASONALBLE_TIME_TO_WAIT = 60000;
      var limit = contact_length;
      Logger.log("limit :"+limit)


      for(var i=Number(num_contacts); i <= contacts.length; i++) {

        var currTime = (new Date()).getTime();
        if(currTime - startTime >= MAX_RUNNING_TIME){

          Logger.log("Value of i in if section : "+i)
          scriptProperties.setProperty("num_contacts",i);
          ScriptApp.newTrigger("getContacts")
          .timeBased()
          .at(new Date(currTime+REASONALBLE_TIME_TO_WAIT))
          .create();

          Logger.log("trigger created for i = "+i)
          break;      
        }
        else{
          if(i < contacts.length)
          {
            allContacts[i] = [];

            contactDetails[0] = contacts[i].getGivenName();
            contactDetails[1] = contacts[i].getFamilyName();


            data = contacts[i].getEmails();
            numData = data.length;
            for(var j = 0; j < numData; j++) {
              dataArray[j] = data[j].getAddress();
            }
            contactDetails[2] = dataArray.join("\n");
            dataArray = [];

            data = contacts[i].getPhones(ContactsApp.Field.MOBILE_PHONE);
            numData = data.length;
            for(var j = 0; j < numData; j++) {
              dataArray[j] = data[j].getPhoneNumber();
            }
            contactDetails[3] = dataArray.join("\n"); 
            dataArray = [];


            data = contacts[i].getPhones(ContactsApp.Field.WORK_PHONE);
            numData = data.length;
            for(var j = 0; j < numData; j++) {
              dataArray[j] = data[j].getPhoneNumber();
            }

            contactDetails[5] = dataArray.join("\n"); 
            dataArray = [];

            // new section for home_phone ----- start
            data = contacts[i].getPhones(ContactsApp.Field.HOME_PHONE);
            numData = data.length;
            for(var j = 0; j < numData; j++){
              dataArray[j] = data[j].getPhoneNumber();
            }
            contactDetails[6] = dataArray.join("\n");
            dataArray = [];
            // new section for home_phone ----- end

            data = contacts[i].getCompanies();
            numData = data.length;
            for(var j = 0; j < numData; j++) {
              dataArray[j] = data[j].getCompanyName();
              extraArray[j] = data[j].getJobTitle();
            }

            contactDetails[7] = dataArray.join("\n");  
            dataArray = [];

            contactDetails[8] = extraArray.join("\n"); 

            data = contacts[i].getAddresses();
            numData = data.length;
            for(var j = 0; j < numData; j++) {
              dataArray[j] = data[j].getAddress();
            }

            contactDetails[9] = dataArray.join("\n");  
            dataArray = [];

            contactDetails[10] = contacts[i].getNotes();

            data = contacts[i].getCustomFields();
            numData = data.length;
            for(var j = 0; j < numData; j++) {
              dataArray[j] = data[j].getValue();
            }

            contactDetails[11] = dataArray.join("\n");  
            dataArray = [];  
            data = [];

            data = contacts[i].getContactGroups();
            numData = data.length;
            for(var j = 0; j < numData; j++) {
              if(data[j].getName() == 'System Group: My Contacts')
              {
                continue;
              }
              else
              {
                dataArray[j] = data[j].getName();
              }
            }

            contactDetails[4] = dataArray.join("\n");  
            dataArray = [];

            contactDetails[12] = 'saved';
            contactDetails[13] = contacts[i].getId();

            for(var j = 0; j < 14; j++) {
              allContacts[i][j] =  contactDetails[j];
            }

          }



        } 

      } 
      Logger.log("last value of i "+i);
      Logger.log("num of contacts "+allContacts.length)
      printContacts(allContacts, contacts.length);
      setProperties_getContacts();
      return;
    }

    //Function to print contacts to the spreadsheet.
    function printContacts(contactsArray, i) {
      var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
      var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();

      var range = sheet.getRange(2, 1, i, 14);
      range.setValues(contactsArray);
    }
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with this particular client-side library, but the API itself has paging built in by using the `max-results` and `start-index` parameters on the list command. If this library doesn't support that than perhaps use the HTTP API directly?

Comment: I'm new to google scripts so @BlakeO'Hare can you please elaborate your point,I didn't understood that

Comment: One way of reducing the request that you are doing is by using a [batch request](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/best_practices#use-batch-operations). You can write scripts to take maximum advantage of the built-in caching, by minimizing the number of reads and writes. Alternating read and write commands are slow. To speed up a script, read all data into an array with one command, perform any operations on the data in the array, and write the data out with one command.

Comment: For more information, here are the [list of quotas for the Google Apps script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas). You can check here the meaning of the limit error that you encountered.

Comment: Thanks @KENdi I'll try using batch requests....thanks for your help